# Firestore not loading data untill previous task is not complete. Not able to set loading priority

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

A have two tasks `taskPlases = refPlaces.get().addOnSuccessListener{ onPlacesLoaded() }` and `taskEmployers = refEmployers.get().addOnSuccessListener{ onEmployersLoaded() }` and onEmployersLoaded() will be always executed after refPlaces loading done. Is there any option to set higher loading priority to taskEmployers or stop/pause taskPlases?

Comment: @AlexMamo Actually it [does](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task?hl=ru#addOnSuccessListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener%3C?%20super%20TResult%3E)) return task. But can I set  higher downloading snapshot priority somehow?

Comment: Oh, yes. In this case, you should consider using Doug's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Play services Task API does not have any sort of priority order for callbacks.  Tasks will always complete as soon as possible.  The underlying SDK that provided the Task is ultimately responsible for providing the result.

If you want to control the order of execution of callbacks, you'll have to write code to manage that.  For your case, it might be as simple as having some sort of gateway function that only allows the next step of your code to continue only after the first two Tasks are complete.  Pseudocode for that:

```
var placesLoaded = false
var employersLoaded = false

refPlaces.get().addOnSuccessListener{
    placesLoaded = true
    checkLoaded()
}

refEmployers.get().addOnSuccessListener{
    employersLoaded = true
    checkLoaded()
}

fun checkLoaded() {
    if (placesLoaded && employersLoaded) {
        doSomethingWithPlacesAndEmployers()
    }
}
```

You could also use Kotlin coroutines to effectively join the asynchronous results.  A play services Task can be used in a coroutine using [this library](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services).